# Error 1601 in iTunes when trying to restore a custom firmware

Tags: restore

What is the solution if you get `Error 1601` in iTunes when trying to restore a custom firmware (shift+restore) and device in DFU mode.

In case it matters, Windows x64, iTunes 10.1, firmware created using sn0wbreeze 2.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your looking for:

- http://www.iphone4jailbreak.org/itunes-restore-error-1601-1604-1600-fix.html

There's also some other possible solutions for the error 1601:

- http://www.simonblog.com/2008/09/25/winpwn-error-6-1600-1601-1604/
- http://modmyi.com/forums/pwnage/281841-error-1601-help-please.html